# Is an extension of two abelian residually finite groups a residually finite group?

Tags: gr.group-theory

We have a short exact sequence $1 \to H \to G \to K \to 1 $, where $H$ and $K$ are **abelian** residually finite groups. My question is: it is true that $G$ is then a residually finite group?.

Comment: No, it's false, there are many counterexamples. It's a duplicate, see this answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/78363/14094

Comment: Thank YCor. Do you know what happening when $H$ and $K$ are both abelian? Do we have the same answer?

Comment: This is not covered by the linked answer. So I'd suggest you edit your question by adding the assumption that $H,K$ are abelian.

Comment: Thanks YCor. I have done :)

Answer (score 2):

In the article *On the finiteness of certain soluble groups* (1959), P. Hall proves that:

**Theorem.** *Every   finitely   generated  abelian-by-nilpotent   group  is residually   finite.  In  particular,  finitely  generated metabelian  groups are always residually finite.*

Of course, the statement is false for groups that are not finitely generated. Even abelian groups may not be finitely generated (such as divisible groups, e.g. $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$).

Answer (score 2):

Just slightly changing the notation: the question asks, given a group with normal subgroup $N$ and quotient $Q=G/N$, such that $N$ and $Q$ are abelian and residually finite, whether $G$ has to be residually finite.

(1) One counterexample is $K\rtimes K^*$ when $K$ is an infinite field of characteristic $p>0$. This is not residually finite (because $K$ is mapped injectively or trivially in every quotient), while $K$ is residually finite.

The group $K^*$ may fail to be residually finite (e.g., when $K$ is algebraically closed), but for $K=\mathbf{F}_p(t)$ it is residually finite (direct product of $\mathbf{F}_p^*$ with a free abelian group of infinite rank).

(2) Here's a counterexample, also split extension, with $Q$ finitely generated (infinite cyclic). Consider $M=\mathbf{F}_p[t^{\pm 1}]/\mathbf{F}_p[t]$, with $T$ the surjective locally nilpotent endomorphism induced by multiplication by $t$. Write $U=\mathrm{Id}+T$. It is thus invertible and we can consider the corresponding semidirect product $G=M\rtimes_U\mathbf{Z}$. Since for the action of $T$, $M$ is a locally nilpotent module, every finite quotient is a nilpotent module, but since $T$ is surjective, this means that the only finite quotient module of $M$ is reduced to $\{0\}$. So $M$ is not a residually finite module (for $T$, and hence for $U$) and thus $G$ is not residually finite.

(3) Here's a counterexample, with $N$ finite. Fix a prime $p$ and fix a non-abelian group $F$ of order $p^3$, with two non-commuting elements $x,y$. Let $F_n$ be a copy of $F$, with the corresponding elements $x_n,y_n$, and $z_n=[x_n,y_n]$. Let $G$ be quotient of the direct sum $\bigoplus_n F_n$ by identifying all central elements $z_n$ (thus defining a single central element $1\neq z=[x_n,y_n]$ of order $p$). Then $G/\langle z\rangle$ is abelian and residually finite. But $G$ is not residually finite: in a finite quotient, there exist $n\neq m$ such that $x_n$ and $x_m$ have the same image. Hence $z=[x_n,y_n]$ and $[x_m,y_n]=1$ have the same image. Hence $z$ is killed in every finite quotient.

(4) For a split extension, if $N$ is finitely generated, it is easy to see that $G$ is residually finite (without the abelian assumption).

(5) If $G$ itself is finitely generated, it is an observation of Ph. Hall that indeed $G$ is residually finite (as mentioned in [Anthony's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/439513/14094)). Indeed, if $Q$ is finitely generated abelian, then $G$ is residually finite if and only if $N$ is a residually finite $Q$-module, and this indeed holds when $N$ is a finitely generated $Q$-module, but not in general as (2) above shows (even when the underlying group $N$ is residually finite).